# Is it appropriate to provide instruction within a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I happened to notice today on SO that the [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas) tag include instruction I've never noticed in other tags.

Excerpt: "For questions about code, **please** include your code *and some data to reproduce your problem*, either in datalines/cards statements or using a `sashelp` dataset like `sashelp.class` or `sashelp.cars`."

Is this appropriate within a tag excerpt?

Comment: It is a reminder that you really do need to provide an mcve if you are asking about code.

Comment: @MichaelT Yeah, but all SO is that way, no?

Comment: Yes, it's part of tag usage. Not like the thousands of plagiarised definitions that are useless

Comment: One would hope so. Some go to [meta posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055).  There are also [tag tips](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634) for some especially problematic tags.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  You know these are collaboratively edited, right? You can't expect them to be consistent across thousands of tags.

Comment: If SAS is still the datawarehouse tool it used to be I can imagine that questions without having the data the code should run on it becomes really impossible to answer. For other tags this might be less so...